# Why doesn't case expression work on SQL query joins used in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a prepared query in two versions, the first one works but the second using CASE WHEN  doesn't :

```
 SELECT  mFrom.user_name AS sender_name, mp.message AS message
 FROM msg_pv mp
 INNER JOIN membresmvc AS mFrom 
    ON mp.id_from = mFrom.id
 WHERE mp.id_to = :id_member
```

CASE WHEN version :

```
 SELECT  mFrom.user_name AS sender_name, mp.message AS message
 FROM msg_pv mp
 INNER JOIN 
    CASE mp.from_type
        WHEN "mb" THEN membresmvc AS mFrom ON mFrom.id = mp.id_from 
    END -- also tried "END CASE"    
 WHERE mp.id_to = :id_member
```

The value of mp.from_type is always "mb" in the msg_pv table. I exactly use [the structure recommented in the MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/case-statement.html). I don't understand why the second query doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think you can use a case there (but I'm no expert in SQL). Also, what do you expect to happen when that case is not matched?

Comment: This case is always matched, the value of mp.from_type is always "mb" in the table, it should work i don't understand why it is not. I want to verify if CASE WHEN works in SQL.

Comment: Agreed on the usage, check out http://www.mysqldiary.com/conditional-joins-in-mysql/

Comment: I guess I don't understand then. If the condition is always true, why have a conditional?

Comment: Because just before I have tried several CASE in the query and i didn't work. Then I wanted to verify if it will work with a simple CASE WHEN like this one, a kind of verification if you want. AS it dosen't work, I wonder if i can use CASE WHEN structure in PHP/SQL ! It seems to be not. Do you understand ?

Comment: you can't do conditional joins like that. and if you could, there's no else clause, so you be joining on nothing if the type ISN'T `mb`.

Comment: Generally speaking, one shouldn't need to do conditional joins: it's a sign that your data structure might need further [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: fairly creative way of conjuring an sql syntax there :-) unfortunately though, language developers would have a hard time delivering that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your *CASE* espression value always evaluates to true, there is no need to have that statement.

However, I think the usage of the *CASE* in your query is wrong. It should be something like as shown below. You can have the *CASE* on the ON *condition* but not on the *JOIN* itself. This way you can join to different columns based on a condition.

This is syntactically correct but not sure what the output would be.

You can validate this statement using this link: [**Instant SQL Formatter**](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm?ref=g_wangz)

*Query*:

```
SELECT      mFrom.user_name AS sender_name, 
            mp.message      AS message 
FROM        msg_pv mp 
INNER JOIN  membresmvc 
ON          ( 
                CASE mp.from_type 
                    WHEN "mb" THEN mFrom.id = mp.id_from 
                    ELSE NULL 
                END 
            ) 
WHERE  mp.id_to = :id_member;
```

## UPDATE

If you need to join to multiple tables based on a condition, then you need to make use of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. You query might look something like this assuming your second table is *second_table* and another value is *"another value"*

```
SELECT          COALESCE(mFrom.user_name, second_table.some_col) AS sender_name, 
                mp.message      AS message 
FROM            msg_pv mp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN membresmvc 
ON              mFrom.id        = mp.id_from 
AND             mp.from_type    = "mb"
LEFT OUTER JOIN second_table 
ON              second_table.id = mp.id_from 
AND             mp.from_type    = "another value"
WHERE           mp.id_to = :id_member;
```

## EXAMPLE

Here is an example that illustrates it. This script was tested in SQL Server 2012 database. It might differ in MySQL. However, the concept of LEFT OUTER JOIN used here is same even in MySQL.

- There are three tables namely `table1`, `table2` and `table3`
- Here we have to join table1 with both table2 and table3 based on the below conditions.
- Join ***colrefid*** in *table1* with *col2* in *table2* if `constant` in *table1* has the value ***t2***.
- Join ***colrefid*** in *table1* with *col3* in *table3* if `constant` in *table1* has the value ***t3***.
- You can see the output at the end

Hope that gives you an idea to join the tables as per your requirements.

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1
(
        col1        INT         NOT NULL
    ,   colrefid    INT         NOT NULL
    ,   constant    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2
(
        col2    INT         NOT NULL
    ,   name    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table3
(
        col3    INT         NOT NULL
    ,   name    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (col1, colrefid, constant) VALUES
    (123, 2, 't2'),
    (784, 3, 't3'),
    (498, 2, 't2');

INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 (col2, name) VALUES
    (2, 'table 2');

INSERT INTO dbo.Table3 (col3, name) VALUES
    (3, 'table 3');

SELECT          t1.col1
            ,   t1.colrefid
            ,   t1.constant
            ,   COALESCE(t2.col2, t3.col3) colvalue
            ,   COALESCE(t2.name, t3.name) colname
FROM            dbo.Table1  t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Table2  t2
ON              t2.col2     = t1.colrefid
AND             t1.constant = 't2'
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Table3  t3
ON              t3.col3     = t1.colrefid
AND             t1.constant = 't3';
```

*Output*:

```
col1 colrefid constant colvalue colname
---- -------- -------- -------- -------
123      2       t2        2    table 2
784      3       t3        3    table 3
498      2       t2        2    table 2
```

Comment: In fact I need to JOIN different table according to the value of mp.from_type ! So the table to join must be inside the CASE WHEN structure ! Can you adapt your code please ?

Comment: DUDE, I LOVE YOU SO MUCH. THANKS A LOT.